# VBA - Change name of the days of the week from any language to English

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA module that takes the names of the days of the week "dddd" (e.g. Monday), compare it with other days of the week and execute the code accordingly. I sent the file to a friend with OS default language is not English and the code is not detecting the names of the days of the week anymore. I assumed that the date value is not equal to the English one.

So how can I change the date to always use English:

```
Dim TodayValue As String
TodayValue = format(Date, "dddd")
```

I saw other function, but I can't run them on VBA! Any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: You could try: `EVALUATE("TEXT(TODAY(),""dddd"")")`

Comment: Why not test using the weekday number instead? That should be universal.

Comment: Had a similar issue with users in 5 countries, so first part of our macro detected the user’s settings for language, ie days & months and then everything followed.

Comment: @Rory I did a test file and send it to my friend to try the Evaluate TodayValue5 = Evaluate("TEXT(NOW(),""[$-041D]dddd"")") might work, thank you. The [$-041D] for English-US (Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I can't change the cells data which is written in English. I'll try this method first.

Comment: @SolarMike This exactly what I am trying to do, I will check how to detect the language and see if it will help.

Comment: I made mistake in my previous comment, the [$-041D] is for Swedish while [$-0409] for English-US. Both methods work fine and show the date in en-US `Evaluate("TEXT(TODAY(),""dddd"")")` or `Evaluate("TEXT(NOW(),""[$-0409]dddd"")")`. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well, you need to always get the weekname of the provided date in english?

So you can use this:

```vb
Dim TodayValue As String
TodayValue = Choose(WeekDay(Date),"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")
```

`WeekDay(Date)` retrieves the number of the day beginning with Sunday and uses the `Choose` procedure to return the regarding name of day.

Comment: That doesn't work if weekdays begin with Monday

Comment: As far as I understand it should work, because `WeekDay` operates independent from the system settings. Thatfor it has the second parameter which defaults to `vbSunday`.

Comment: It works fine. The output shows Tuesday instead of tisdag (Tuesday in Swedish).

Comment: Although your expression answers the question, @StureS has a point, as `Weekday` doesn't return the number for a weekday's name but a number for the date's position in the week having 1 as the first day of the week. Thus, the native function `WeekdayName(Weekday(#2021-02-24#))` returns _Thursday_ if your first day of the week is Monday. The correct expression will be `WeekdayName(Weekday(#2021-02-24#, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek))` which returns _Wednesday_.

Comment: @StureS: Adding to the comment above: A function that would mimic `WeekdayName` taking a weekday value as argument and would return English weekday names instead of localised names, will take a little more.

Answer (score 2):

You should never rely on localised values in your code.

To specify a weekday, always the *DayOfWeek* value, then format it whenever you need it displayed:

```vb
Dim DayToday    As VbDayOfWeek

DayToday = Weekday(Date, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
    
    
Debug.Print WeekdayName(DayToday, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
```

For the invariant (English) weekday name, we use this function which exactly mimics the native function `WeekdayName`:

```
' Returns the English weekday name for the passed weekday number.
' Accepted numbers are 1 to 7. Other values will raise an error, as
' will an invalid value for FirstDayOfWeek.
' If Abbreviate is True, the returned name is abbreviated.
'
' 2020-11-13. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function WeekdayNameInvariant( _
    ByVal Weekday As Long, _
    Optional ByVal Abbreviate As Boolean, _
    Optional ByVal FirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = VbDayOfWeek.vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) _
    As String
    
    Const AbbreviatedLength As Integer = 2
    
    Dim WeekdayNames( _
        FirstWeekday To _
        LastWeekday)        As String
    Dim Name                As String
    
    If Not (IsWeekday(Weekday) And IsWeekday(FirstDayOfWeek)) Then
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Non-localized (invariant) weekday names.
    WeekdayNames(VBA.Weekday(1, FirstDayOfWeek)) = "Sunday"
    WeekdayNames(VBA.Weekday(2, FirstDayOfWeek)) = "Monday"
    WeekdayNames(VBA.Weekday(3, FirstDayOfWeek)) = "Tuesday"
    WeekdayNames(VBA.Weekday(4, FirstDayOfWeek)) = "Wednesday"
    WeekdayNames(VBA.Weekday(5, FirstDayOfWeek)) = "Thursday"
    WeekdayNames(VBA.Weekday(6, FirstDayOfWeek)) = "Friday"
    WeekdayNames(VBA.Weekday(7, FirstDayOfWeek)) = "Saturday"
    
    If Abbreviate = True Then
        Name = Left(WeekdayNames(Weekday), AbbreviatedLength)
    Else
        Name = WeekdayNames(Weekday)
    End If
    
    WeekdayNameInvariant = Name

End Function


' Returns True if Expression can be a value of VbDayOfWeek.
' Returns False if Expression is Null or an invalid value.
'
' 2017-01-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function IsWeekday( _
    ByVal Expression As Variant) _
    As Boolean
    
    Dim Result  As Boolean

    Select Case Expression
        Case _
            VbDayOfWeek.vbMonday, _
            VbDayOfWeek.vbTuesday, _
            VbDayOfWeek.vbWednesday, _
            VbDayOfWeek.vbThursday, _
            VbDayOfWeek.vbFriday, _
            VbDayOfWeek.vbSaturday, _
            VbDayOfWeek.vbSunday, _
            VbDayOfWeek.vbUseSystemDayOfWeek
            Result = True
    End Select

    IsWeekday = Result

End Function
```

Comment: How can I change the date format to English-US? Where can I read more information about it!

Comment: Date format? Your question is about weekday names ...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried the code, the output shows the weekday name according to the OS language, while I want English-US all the time. So, is there anything I can add to the code to make it in en-us? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, see extended answer, please.